# I have IDs from many tweets; how can I fetch their full information with the Twitter API without exceeding the rate limit?

Tags: twitter

I have IDs from many tweets, and I'd like to fetch their full information from Twitter in order to do some data analysis. The obvious API method (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/show/:id) appears to take only one ID at a time. This is a problem because the number of tweets we need to analyze is well more than the API limit of 350 calls per hour.

Thus: is there some way to get full information for a *set* of tweet IDs, not just one, or alternately to submit many REST calls in the same HTTP request and have it count only once against the API limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's unfortunately no bulk lookup offered for Tweets. You'll need to perform requests one at a time and scope your project to cope with the rate limitations. If you have friends who would like to help you, you could potentially ask them to authorize your application and leverage their permission to gain access to more requests.